# How to check if one table is replica of other table in SQL?

Tags: sql

How to find if one table is replica of other table in SQL

Comment: Which one? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to verify if two tables have exactly the same data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129717/how-to-verify-if-two-tables-have-exactly-the-same-data)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can compare the results of:

```
SELECT checksum_agg(checksum(*))
FROM Table1;

SELECT checksum_agg(checksum(*))
FROM Table2;
```

You could create a join with these as sub-queries if you want, too.

You may wish to use `binary_checksum()` instead of `checksum()`.  [The doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) says that `checksum()` will treat strings that are equal as equal according to the collation (i.e., `'hello'` and `'HELLO'` if the collation is case-insensitive), while [`binary_checksum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx) compares the raw binary values of characters.

Answer (score 0):

This works for MySQL:

```
CHECKSUM TABLE table_1, table_2;
```