# How to compare if two tables got the same content?

Tags: sql

How can I compare if two tables got the same content in sql?

Comment: Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129744/10074438

Comment: If T-SQL there you can use [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Please add more to your question. What have you tried? what do you mean by the same content? are you referring to all the columns and all the rows? Try adding an example to show us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Possibile duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077807/sql-query-to-return-differences-between-two-tables

Comment: I have no code i just have to answer a question, how to compare the content of two tables for similarity and i am not sure how to do it?

Comment: Do a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXISTS`

```
    Select case when count(*) >0 
     Then
    'Common content exists' 
     Else 
     'Nothing in common' 
     End
    from table1 t1 where
   EXISTS (select 1 from table2 t2 where 
    t2.id=t1.id )
```