# Is there an Azure SQL Database equivalent to MySQL's "CHECKSUM TABLE", and should it be used to check if two tables are identical?

Tags: mysql, sql, azure-sql-database

I was looking for a way to check if two tables in the same database are identical (both contents and schema), and came over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129717/how-to-verify-if-two-tables-have-exactly-the-same-data).

The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129780/12206312) for the question uses (from my understanding) a MySQL specific. When trying to run the code in an Azure SQL Database I get this error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.`.

Instead of using `CHECKSUM TABLE` to see if the two tables are identical we ended up using the two following queries:

```
select * from util.table1
except
select * from dbo.table2

select * from dbo.table2
except
select * from util.table1
```

So I essentially have three questions regarding this:

1. Does Azure SQL Database have an equivalent to [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129780/12206312)?
2. Should we even use that query for checking if two tables are identical?
3. Is the option we went for (using except) a viable option? if not, why not, and what can we do better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **CHECKSUM** function in **Azure SQL Database** returns the checksum value computed over a table row, or over an expression list. Checksum returns the hash value over its argument list.

Example:

In the below example, the checksum value returns the computed value of the table row.

[image]

To compare the data from two tables, the best way is to use the [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

> **EXCEPT** returns any distinct values from the query left of the EXCEPT operator. Those values return as long the right query doesn't return those values as well.

Tables data:

[image]

With Except:

[image]